# Need help with Javascript/CSS to manipulate html table layout for bowling scorecard

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create a responsive table for a bowling scorecard. I want the table to split up depending on the width of the screen, preferably into thirds (where the first row would be frames 1, 2 & 3 , the second row would be frames 4, 5 & 6, and so forth) and then finally into a single column (where each row is just one frame). I  have the html/css for a full row but I have no idea how to make it responsive to split depending on screen width.

[image: full width scorecard]

[image: 3 split scorecard]

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is essentially a request to write code.

Comment: I actually realized that stackoverflow would probably be a better place to ask for help. I wasn't sure if I should delete this post and repost over there.

Comment: Before re-posting on SO, please put more explanation and detail into your question. Otherwise, your question will quickly be closed there. It would help if you provided the relevant code you already have and what you've already attempted in order to represent the split. Also explain why your previous attempts didn't work as expected. Providing that information will move you away from a "GIMME TEH CODEZ" style question into one that's seeking help for a specific, answerable problem. And FWIW, the question here on Progs has 4 close votes already, so you may want to just kill it off.

Comment: You should try to use css media queries.

Comment: "I have the html/css for a full row" ... can you please post that so that we have something to work with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use a `<table>`. Use this HTML...

```
<ul>
  <li>Frame 1</li>
  <li>Frame 2</li>
  <li>Frame 3</li>
  <li>Frame 4</li>
  <li>Frame 5</li>
  <li>Frame 6</li>
  <li>Frame 7</li>
  <li>Frame 8</li>
  <li>Frame 9</li>
  <li>Frame 10</li>
</ul>
```

...with this css...

```
li{
  list-style-type: none; /*Removes bullet points*/
  float:left; /*Moves div to next row if the window is too narrow*/
  background:red; border:2px #000 solid; /*For demo*/
}
```

...and check out the demo: http://www.cssdesk.com/EWeZn

Comment: Thank you kindly, this helps solve my problem...I guess I over complicated the whole thing.